# plotting streamplot is so slow in python3

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Anaconda, and I think this problem is even before I use Anaconda.
Everytime I want to plot streamline with basemap, it takes a very long time to plot one figure.
Here is an example:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


fuv = nc.Dataset('~/era5_uv850_20200601_00_01.nc')
uwnd = fuv.variables['u'] 
vwnd = fuv.variables['v'] 
uwnd = uwnd[0,:,:]
vwnd = vwnd[0,:,:]

lon= fuv.variables['longitude']
lat= fuv.variables['latitude']

map = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=    0.,urcrnrlat=20.,llcrnrlon=90.5,urcrnrlon=120.5,resolution='i')
x,y=map(*np.meshgrid(lon,lat))

plt.clf()
map.streamplot(x,y,uwnd,vwnd,30)
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcountries()
plt.show()
```

The data from ERA5 webpage: [Copernicus Data Storage](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/search?type=dataset)
or you can download it here: [WeTransfer Link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b0264253a1355437647e0936bec3b91720200823093359/32b60b)

Is the slowness a common issue?

Comment: better create minimal working code with some data which we could run and see problem.

Comment: I have edited the original post.

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's probably my laptop. I'm using the late 2013 Macbook Pro, 2.6 Ghz Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3. Intel Iris 1536 MB. 
Any plot related to wind (vector or streamlines) takes longer than it used to be.

Comment: you can try to run it on servers [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com)